# Calling a windows program(ms paint) using php

Tags: php, html, windows

Is this possible? Once my if condition is satisfied, it will open ms paint show a .tiff file?

Comment: On the user's browser? No.

Comment: The php instance is running on the machine you want ms-paint to pop up? I.e. _not_ a request from a client to a server (that is processing the php script) and then have ms-paint pop up on the client?

Comment: FYI- part of the downvote text is "The question does not show any research effort".  That's why I downvoted, and likely what caused the other one.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not in the browser

Comment: @VolkerK yes i want ms paint to pop up, and open a .tiff file

Comment: How about [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Comment: "@VolkerK yes i want ms paint to pop up, and open a .tiff file" - ok, and what about the remainder of my question? The important part?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Windows software using JavaScript:

```
function runWinZip() {
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
shell.run("winzip.exe");
}
```

And with php:

```
 <?php
    echo 'function runWinZip() {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
    shell.run("winzip.exe");}';
 ?>
```